# Get single record from observablecollection

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

I am developing an app for windowsphone 8 an ran into the following:

I have a observable collection which contains multiple usernames and user passwords Also, there is an ID with every user.

How can I get the information of one user (lets say by id) and bind this information to a listbox or textblock in my ui.

Comment: something like listbox.DataSource = collection.Where((e)=>e.Id == id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourListBox.ItemsSource = yourCollection.Where((x) => x.id == id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listbox.datasource = list.select( x => x ).where( x.id == id);
```

Hope it helps. I suggest maybe using a [CollectionView](http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html) that you bind to the listbox, and filter the list using the code above, and the listbox updates itself.

Comment: I have got a ObservableCollection, does that make it any different then a List.Select?  And what does (x=> x) do?

Comment: It's ok if you use ObservableCollection because it implements IEnumerable and you can use LINQ, a nice way to manage,query lists : http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b . (x => x) selects all elements from lists. For example : ( x => x.category) will return a list of categories for each element from list.

Comment: Is it possible to save the value i extract from the list, to another list and then bind the second list to the ui?